# Extracting specific columns from a string of lines

Tags: python, regex

I have a text string within a bigger string which is of the following:

```
FLIGHT / DATE             MAWB                   HAWB 
SQ8345                        84937590            SMIS20935
GOODS COLLECTED FROM
```

So basically 3 lines above with first 2 lines having 3 entries each and last line is just GOODS COLLECTED FROM string

In some cases the same above can have this:

```
ROAD REFERENCE           MASTER BILL                  HOUSE BILL 
SQ8345                        84937590            SMIS20935
GOODS COLLECTED FROM
```

So same thing just that the heading for FLIGHT / DATE is sometimes replaced with ROAD REFERENCE and so do the other two heading in first line.

I want an output like below. Meaning even if MAWB is called as MASTER BILL and HAWB is present as HOUSE BILL, final output can rename them as prior version (as that is the most often present name)

```
{"MAWB" : 84937590, 
  "HAWB" :  SMIS20935
}
```

My idea is to extract the whole 3 lines from "FLIGHT / DATE" or "ROAD REFERENCE" until "GOODS COLLECTED FROM" line.

Then use splitlines on that extracted string and split as list of list. Finally use zip() and look for second lists to form the above dict.

I did this first:

```
 re.search(
    r'(?s)(MAWB\s*HAWB.+?GOODS COLLECTED FROM)', output).group()
```

and got this as a string

```
'MAWB              HAWB\n      
/ SQ8345 /             84937590       SMIS20935\n    
 GOODS COLLECTED FROM'
```

So this is extracting all three as a string of lines which is helpful as we can then use striplines on top of that and extract as list of lists.

However the first col heading is missing, so did this:

```
re.search(
    r'(?s)(FLIGHT.*DATE|ROAD REFERENCE\s*HAWB|MASTER BILL\s*.+?GOODS COLLECTED FROM)', output).group()
```

But I only get

```
FLIGHT / DATE.
```

Ideally I wanted the above should give:

```
FLIGHT / DATE             MAWB                   HAWB 
SQ8345                        84937590            SMIS20935
GOODS COLLECTED FROM
```

on three different lines. And then I can use

```
s = [
    re.split(r'\s{2,}', line.strip()) for line in s.splitlines() if line !=''
]
```

to get the above lines as list of lists of length 3.

What am I missing in the above regex which is not extracting whole string till GOODS COLLECTED FROM and is only getting the first part (FLIGHT / DATE)

UPDATE:

I tried this: Seemsto give the right answer. Just wanted to check if it can cause any issues

```
mawb=  re.search(
    r'(?s)((FLIGHT|ROAD REFERENCE).*(MAWB|MASTER BILL)\s*.+?GOODS COLLECTED FROM)', output).group()

mawb= [
    re.split(r'\s{2,}', line.strip()) for line in (mawb.splitlines()) if line !=''
]

{pair[0]: pair[1] for i, pair in enumerate(zip(*mawb[:-1])) if i!=0}


{'MAWB': '84937590', 'HAWB': 'SMIS20935'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:[\w/]+(?:[ ][\w/]+)*)[ ]{2,}([\w/]+(?:[ ][\w/]+)*)[ ]{2,}([\w/]+(?:[ ][\w/]+)*)[ ]*$\r?\n^(?:[\w/]+(?:[ ][\w/]+)*)[ ]{2,}([\w/]+(?:[ ][\w/]+)*)[ ]{2,}([\w/]+(?:[ ][\w/]+)*)[ ]*$\r?\nGOODS[ ]+COLLECTED[ ]+FROM[ ]*$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPQSv7/1)

Comment: My God!. Thats an insane regex u used. Impressive. I did this (pls check edit). Do u think that might cause some issues somewhere especially with the "|" operator for checking either of FLIGHT / ROAD REFERENCE or MAWB/MASTER BILL.

Comment: Same principle, just changed to `[\w/]` every where

Comment: If I want to store this whole regex in a yaml file and then read that regex from that yaml file in python script instead of filling the whole script with multiple regex,do u know how to do that? Store in a yaml file and read it in a python script to be used as regex? Thank u

Comment: I dont now how that is doable